# How to do autorendering in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'm guessing its just not done since I can't find any reference to this anywhere, even people asking without response. Although I'm hoping Symfony calls it something else.

How can I get Symfony to auto render `views/{controller}/{action}.html.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@meze's answers are both more desirable than out of the box behaviour.

However I think the SensioFrameworkExtraBundle he pointed me to has given me the clue that I needed to achieve this without replacing my own route.

That is to hook into the [kernel view event](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/internals.html#kernel-view-event).

Its purpose is specifically stated as:

> The purpose of the event is to allow some other return value to be converted into a Response.

I'm assuming then that it can be used to convert a null return from the controller action to a response.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible in standard edition of Symfony. However, routing is just one of its [components](http://symfony.com/components). So if you really want, you can create your own component and use it instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1) Use [SensioFrameworkExtraBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html#annotations-for-controllers) - it allows to use @Template annotation. (It's included in SE).

2) Write your own method. I found it annoying to write @Template and any annotations in controllers every time so I added this method in the base controller (it's only an example, examine before using it in production):

```
public function view(array $parameters = array(), Response $response = null, $extension = '')
{
    $extension = !empty($extension) ? $extension : $this->templateExtension;
    $view = ViewTemplateResolver::resolve($this->get('request')->get('_controller'), get_called_class());
    return $this->render($view . '.' . $extension, $parameters, $response);
}


class ViewTemplateResolver
{

    public static function resolve($controller, $class)
    {
        $action = preg_replace('/(.*?:|Action$)/', '', $controller);
        if (preg_match('~(\w+)\\\\(\w+Bundle).*?(\w+(?=Controller$))~', $class, $name)) {
            return implode(':', array($name[1] . $name[2], $name[3], $action));
        }
    }
}
```

Now in the controller we can do: `return $this->view();`

Answer (score 0):

When you do routing with annotations instead of yaml, you can add a `@Template()` to your action method and it's rendering the default template as requested by you.

To do this, change your routing to annotations:

```
AcmeDemoBundle:
    resource: "@PAcmeDemoBundle/Controller/"
    type: annotation
    prefix: /
```

Within your controllers, add this for each action:

```
/**
 * @Route("/index", name="demo_index")
 * @Template()
 */
```

Actually I don't know if there is a way to get this behaviour when not using annotations. But as there seems to be logic for this, there might be one.